# How do I analyse this pulley-trolley system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

**"find a force F such that the blocks are stationary relative to the trolley. All surfaces, wheels and pulley are assumed to be friction-less"**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AErg.png): [image]

This is a very common mechanics problem and has been mentioned on this site before. I tried to solve this question from the pulley frame of reference using pseudo forces and it was quite easy to do so, but i cant wrap my mind around a few things.

**1)Why is the tension dependent on the acceleration of the trolley?**
the tension in string is found to be equal to $\frac  {m1m2(g+a)}{m1+m2}$ where a is the acceleration of the trolley relative to the ground. What is the intuition behind the it being dependent on a? Does this have something to do with the reaction force of pulley on the string

***2) How can acceleration of the trolley prevent downward motion of block B?***
if the trolley can only exert horizontal force on block B, how does it end up stopping it from falling for some value of a?

**3) How do i effectively analyse this problem from the non inertial frame of reference without the use of pseudo forces?**

Comment: Are masses  in equilibrium ?

Comment: sorry, iwill edit the question to clarify.

Comment: A different way of looking at this problem conceptually: How much force to the left must be placed on $m_1$ to keep it from moving?  $F=ma$, so you can calculate the acceleration on $m_1$ in its reference frame, and apply $F=ma$ to all 3 masses to calculate the $F$ in the question.

Comment: Please ask just one question per post

Comment: @BioPhysicist I believe that the questions are closely related to each other. It would be weird to make 3 separate posts for parts of the same question

Comment: But they aren't the same question. They are three different questions (which is why your title is general/vague). There isn't anything wrong with making multiple posts with distinct questions arising from the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why is the tension dependent on the acceleration of the trolley?

The acceleration of the large block $M$ and the attached pulley does put a force on the string because the string must accelerate with the pulley. This increases the tension of the string and so creates a larger force on both blocks $m_1$ and $m_2$.

2. How can acceleration of the trolley prevent downward motion of block B?

There are two ways to think of this. First, strings always exert tension along their length, so an increase in tension caused by the pushing of the pulley on the string creates an upward force on the hanging $m_2$ because that is the only direction the string can pull. Second, the string pulls on the pulley with equal magnitude down and to the left (tension is preserved across a massless, frictionless pulley). So, the reaction force must be up and to the right by Newton's Third Law. So, the pulley can create an upward force on the block $m_2$ which increases with acceleration.

3. How do i effectively analyse this problem from the non inertial frame of reference without the use of pseudo forces?

The same way you would do any other physics problem:

1. Draw a picture,
2. Lay down a coordinate system,
3. List each moving mass,
4. List the forces on each mass,
5. Write equations of motion for each mass using Newton's Second Law and any constraints,
6. Solve the whole system.

Step 1 is done in the question.

For Step 2, let's use right and up as positive directions, left and down as negative directions.

Step 3, we have three masses: $M$, $m_1$, and $m_2$.

Step 4 and Step 5 is where the work starts.

The mass $M$ has three forces acting on it: the applied force $F$ to the right, the string tension $T$ to the left at the pulley, and the normal force to the left from block $m_2$.
$$F - T - F_N = Ma$$
where $a$ is the acceleration of $M$ (right is positive). *Important note:* the tension $T$ and the normal force $F_N$ have negative signs because they point to the left. This means that $T$ and $F_N$ should have positive values once you solve for them since they represent magnitudes.

Next, $m_1$ is acted on by the string tension $T$ to the right.
$$T = m_1a_1$$
where $a_1$ is the acceleration of $m_1$ (right is positive).

Finally, $m_2$ is acted upon by the string tension $T$ upward, gravity ($m_2g$) downward, and the normal force from block $M$ to the right.
$$T - m_2g = m_2a_2$$
$$F_N = m_2a$$
where $a_2$ is the acceleration of $m_2$ (up is positive) and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity ($+9.8\,m/s^2$). We know that the tension on $m_1$ and $m_2$ is the same since the pulley is massless and frictionless (later, when you start studying rotational mechanics and torque, this will not necessarily be the case). We also know that the horizontal acceleration of the block $m_2$ is the same as the block $M$ because $m_2$ has no way of moving away ahead of block $M$.

We now have 5 unknowns ($a$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $F_N$, and $T$) and four equations. We have one more constraint equation due to $m_1$ and $m_2$ being tied together. This forces their accelerations relative to the block $M$ to be the same since their distance from each other must be constant.
$$a_2 = a - a_1$$.
If $a_1$ is larger than $a$, then the $m_2$ block will be accelerating downwards since the $m_1$ block will eventually overtake the $M$ block. Remember that $a_1$ is measured in the ground frame.

From here, you should be able to (Step 6) solve for the acceleration of $a_1$ in terms of the applied force $F$. Then, when you want to find when the blocks $m_1$ and $m_2$ are stationary with respect to the large block $M$, set $a_1 = a$ so that the block on top keeps up with the large block.

One more pedantic note, we can ignore the vertical forces on $M$ and $m_1$ and the horizontal forces on $m_2$ since these will be balanced by normal forces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Cleared. A lot f doubts. I have a few follow up questions; if you would be so kind. Firstly, I get that 1) implies 2) but and why does the String accelerate with the pulley? We, at no point, took into account the reaction force of the pulley on the string. And secondly, will the horizontal acceleration relative to ground of m1 be equal to the downward component of m2’s acceleration relative to ground, just like they are relative to the pulley? ( which is what the usual assumption is)

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH First, I was wrong about $a_1 = a_2$. That would only happen if $M$ were not accelerating. The acceleration $a_2$ has to be the difference between $a_1$ and $a$. This has been fixed in the answer. Second, since the string is massless, the only requirement is that the string accelerate according to what it is attached to. Any force on the string just changes the tension in the string.

Comment: just to be clear, a2 refers to the magnitude of the vertical component of m2 right? which in this case would be 0

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH That's right.

Comment: How does tension act on the M, when it is not connected to the string?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz The tension in the string acts on the pulley, which is rigidly connected to $M$. If you push hard enough on $M$, then $m_2$ will rise. Some work must be done to lift $m_2$, which means that the $M$ will accelerate less than if $m_2$ were rigidly bolted to $M$. The only force available to do this is the string tension. Also, imagine if the applied force $F$ was zero. The block $m_2$ falls, pulling $m_1$ to the right. By conservation of horizontal momentum, the large block $M$ has to move to the right. The only available force to do this is the string tension.

Comment: Thank you for your response.But the mass M isn't connected to the string ,then how is tension acting on it?You said that the pulley has tension acting on it and hence the mass M is affected.Can u please elaborate?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz The string is wrapped around the pulley. Tension in a string is felt throughout the string, not just at the ends. So, any temsion in the string is felt by the pulley, and thus mass M.

Comment: I see .So there are horizontal and vertical components of the tension experienced by the mass M

Comment: Also isn't the mass M technically connected to the pulley by a support of some kind?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz Yes, the horizontal part of the string attached to $m_1$ creates a horizontal force to the left on the pulley and the vertical part of the string attached to $m_2$ creates a vertical force downward on the pulley. Since the pulley is rigidly connected to $M$, $M$ feels this force as well.

Comment: So string applies force on support which applies force on M?

Comment: And there would be a vertical component of tension also then?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz Yes on both questions.