# I have some problem about Force analysis

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image]

The slant block(M1) is placed on a horizontal surface, and there is an object(M2) on it.

There is no friction between objects。If a horizontal force(F1) is applied to the inclined block，
So what happens between objects。

How does horizontal force affect objects above。

Objects(M2) are subject to gravity and support,Is there any other force?

Because the support is uncertain, the two components cannot be accurately decomposed。
At least the support is vertical, but the size is unknown. So the decomposition can't be determined. How should I judge

If the horizontal force increases the support of the object(M2)，How to decompose the horizontal force on the inclined block。

If the horizontal force is decomposed into a component(F2) of a plane perpendicular to an angle of 20 degrees，The other component(F3) is diagonally downward。

I think this component(F3) is very strange,If we decompose this component again.

Decompose this component(F3) into horizontal and vertical,Although it can be broken down at will，but the contradiction between the vertical component and the horizontal force(F1)。

F2 and F3 are not sure, I can't make sure it's decomposed correctly。There are many possibilities。

At least, F3 cannot be determined because the support(F2) to the object cannot be determined.

Before that, whether the object(M2) was only subjected to gravity and supporting force.Will M2 receive other forces?Or only the horizontal force(F1) against the oblique block, which only increases the supporting force of the object(M2)

Can you solve my doubts? I'll thank you very much！

Before not affecting the previous reading to add some of my main doubts

I have some questions about the vectors.The horizontal force(F1) is decomposed into two vectors。one vectors(F2 Perpendicular to slope),another vectors(F3 It's determined by the vertical vector and the horizontal vector).

For M,No matter how it is decomposed, the resultant force is a horizontal force.It doesn't affect the object(M)

But for m,F2 can increase support force.F3 doesn't seem to make sense. It looks like F3 can decompose vectors。Because it's not acting on objects(m),Only upward vectors can affect objects(m).

(1)Is this decomposition and what I think right? What is the meaning of F3

(2)For certain forces, but the values are different.Under the determination of mass and force，Find out different situations for Different forces。Only through the determination of force and mass, the acceleration is uncertain。

About the problem of (2),I can't think of how to get the acceleration of objects M and m.Because under the influence of horizontal force，Object(M) get a force about pressure，and Object(m) get a force about support，N is not equal to m*g*cos(theta),Cannot analyze the movement of objects individually.

For the overall analysis，Because it's impossible to know one of the accelerations of a and B.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUgwE.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “support”?

Comment: i am so sorry ,Because of the problem of translation。the“support”is a force of support

Comment: My question is, if there is a horizontal force on the oblique block，

How does it affect objects on a slope

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I analyse this pulley-trolley system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562471/how-do-i-analyse-this-pulley-trolley-system) I know it's not the exact same question but the underlying concept is same.

Comment: oh！thanks you very much ！i will seeit。

Comment: Actually, I'm afraid of this problem。If this model does not change, the horizontal force is the object m2。Or the model becomes horizontal，I know the force analysis very well。For the original model, but I can't think of this situation。i will see it and Try to explain the problem。

Comment: Hi 能够可能. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your sketch I'm going to choose +x to the left and +y down.  Similarly for x' and y' moving with the slant block.  I will use m to indicate $M_2$.  The slant block will move to the left (+x) with an acceleration A. Then m will have two components of acceleration in the inertial frame (assuming A is small):  $a_x$ = A + a' cos(θ)   and  $a_y$ = a' sin(θ).  Where a' is the acceleration of m down the surface. There will be a normal force, N, up and to the left acting on m, and an equal reaction force acting back on the slant block.  The force equations become F – N sin(θ) = $M_1$A for the slant block and also
N sin( θ) = m$a_x$  and  mg – N cos( θ) = m$a_y$
I believe the equations will still work for large values of A, but the components of a' will turn out to be negative.  For the block to remain in place on the incline, set a' = 0.

Comment: thanks you! it's very useful.

Comment: If you only know the mass、force and angle，Assuming F is a certain value
This value does not take a special value, such as M and m do not move together。

Comment: All of the accelerations are determined by a given F.

Comment: What else can I use to establish an equation? The accelerations of M and m are uncertain, and because the contact force cannot be determined, the objects cannot be analyzed separately.The whole is more difficult to analyze。

Comment: If F is removed, I can know that the pressure must be m*g*cos(theta).because of the horizontal force, the pressure of the object cannot be determined.

Comment: If object m is stationary relative to object M，The acceleration of the object(M and m) relative to the ground is the same,Can build an equation(a=F/(M+m)).The resultant force of the gravity and supporting force of the object m is horizontal.In fact, only the supporting force can change the direction of the resultant force.
But for non-special cases, the acceleration of the two is not the same in the system.I think only F can be calculated, but I have no idea yet.

Comment: For special cases,a right triangle is formed by supporting force, gravity and resultant force (ma).This can get some relationships about m*g/N=cos(theta)  (m*a)/N=sin(theta) . Finally got N=m*g/cos(theta) or   N=m*F/((M+m)*sin(theta)) by a=F/(M+m)  and (m*a)/N=sin(theta)

Comment: The five equations I provided above above can be solved (with effort) to get a' in terms of F and the other givens. Then one can find N in terms of a' and A in terms of a' and N.

Comment: Thank you very much！My doubts are resolved, but the integration is too complicated.I can't integrate it into a simple formula.

Comment: Integration is not required. You can eliminate unknowns from the five simultaneous equations.

Comment: hello,There is a good solution here,I put the picture on it.